# To get login userId using nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get login `userId` using below code but it always shows only `userId` present in the position of index of 0(zero).

### api.js

```
var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
db.collection('users').findOne(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    var record = {
        "Product_Name": json.Product_Name,
        "Brand": json.Brand,
        "Color": json.Color,
        "Image": json.Image,
        "Price": json.Price,
        "Rating": json.Rating,
        "Description": json.Description,
        "Category": json.Category,
        "Url": urla,
        "userId":user._id,
    }

    db.collection('proInfo').insertOne( record, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Inserted a document into the proInfo collection.");
        callback(result);
    });
});
};
```

In the above code I get the `userId` from `users` collection and insert the information to `proInfo` collection, while inserting it always insert the `userId` of first user i.e. user present in location of index 0. But I want the `userId` of login person. How to fix this somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It would do that. That's because you are not providing a query document to the `findOne` function. Also I don't think there is any need to find a user from the `users` collection as you are just using a user's `_id` field. so you can simply do this:

```
var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
var record = {
        "Product_Name": json.Product_Name,
        "Brand": json.Brand,
        "Color": json.Color,
        "Image": json.Image,
        "Price": json.Price,
        "Rating": json.Rating,
        "Description": json.Description,
        "Category": json.Category,
        "Url": urla,
        "userId":userIdYouGetFromRequest,
    };

db.collection('proInfo').insertOne( record, function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Inserted a document into the proInfo collection.");
    callback(result);
});    };
```

If you want other user related fields to be inserted in the proInfo collection, then edit your call to the `findOne` method with a query document. Something like this :

```
var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
db.collection('users').findOne({_id: userIdYouGetFromRequest}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    var record = {
        "Product_Name": json.Product_Name,
        "Brand": json.Brand,
        "Color": json.Color,
        "Image": json.Image,
        "Price": json.Price,
        "Rating": json.Rating,
        "Description": json.Description,
        "Category": json.Category,
        "Url": urla,
        "userId":user._id,
    };

    db.collection('proInfo').insertOne( record, function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Inserted a document into the proInfo collection.");
        callback(result);
    });
});    
};
```

**Note** : the `userIdYouGetFromRequest` is something you will have to pass in the request body from the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Normally findOne() funcion accepts a `query object` that is used to **identify** the document in the collection. Since you have not provided any `query object` to identify the document, findOne returns the first document it finds in the collection. Read the MongoDB docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#definition

NOTE: Please avoid programming in NodeJS using callbacks and use Promises features support in ES6. It will simplify async coding and prevents [callback hell](http://stackabuse.com/avoiding-callback-hell-in-node-js/) to maximum.

If I were you I would modify your code into:

```
var insertDocument = function (db, callback) {
  var queryObj = {
    "userId": user._id
  };

  return db.collection('users').findOne(queryObj)
    .then(function (user) {
      //If the find query was successful, this function will be
      //called with the document returned.
      var record = {
        "Product_Name": json.Product_Name,
        "Brand": json.Brand,
        "Color": json.Color,
        "Image": json.Image,
        "Price": json.Price,
        "Rating": json.Rating,
        "Description": json.Description,
        "Category": json.Category,
        "Url": urla,
        "userId": user._id
      };

      return db.collection('proInfo').insertOne(record)
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log("Inserted a document into the proInfo collection.");
          return result;
        },
        //Handle error for second DB call.
        //If db call to insert doc fails, promise will be rejected
        function(err){
          assert.equal(err, null);
        }
      );
    },
    //Handle error for first DB call.
    //If db call to find users fails, promise will be rejected
    function(err){
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
};
```

Please learn Promises before attempting this code. Its a feature that has received wide adoption among community.